# How to retrieve graph impressions with string action types

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am sending a request for graph insights with the action type breakdown like this one given in an example on Facebook page :     `https://graph.facebook.com/XXXXXXXX/app_insights/story_publishes?since=1418112000&until=1426748400&summary=true&breakdowns[0]=client&breakdowns[1]=action_type&breakdowns[2]=auth_state&date_format=U`
The result is however difficult to read because the type of action is represented by a numeric value (uuid) like this: "action_type"=>"465905580137487", so I dont know what it relates to- checkin, share or photo upload. Also for different apps those uuids are also different. Does anyone know what call I need to make to get the action type names as strings? Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You need to call this URL:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{action_id}
```

where action_id is the value returned by action_type. You'll receive the action details on the response.

Comment: I am afraid that by calling this action I am trying to retrieve information about an app with the facebook app id the same as this action is because I am getting OAuth error.